# Angular: Use only one modal to create and edit a person

Tags: angular

I want to use only one modal for creating and editing a person and not two.
Creating the person works.
If the person is to be updated, then the first name and last name are not in the input element. Also, the person is not updated.

This is my current code:

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { DialogComponent } from './dialog/dialog.component';
import { Person } from './person';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  styles: [``],
  template: `
    <button (click)="createPerson()">Create Person</button>
    <button (click)="updatePerson(persons[0])">Update Person</button>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  persons: Person[] = [];
  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}

  createPerson() {
    this.dialog
      .open(DialogComponent, {})
      .afterClosed()
      .subscribe((person: Person) => {
        this.persons.push(person);
        console.log(this.persons);
      });
  }

  updatePerson(person: Person) {
    this.dialog
      .open(DialogComponent, { data: person })
      .afterClosed()
      .subscribe(() => {
        console.log(this.persons);
      });
  }
}
```

dialog.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { Person } from '../person';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog',
  templateUrl: './dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialog.component.scss'],
})
export class DialogComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public person: Person
  ) {}
  firstName: string = '';
  lastName: string = '';
  ngOnInit(): void {}

  addOrUpdatePerson() {
    const person = {
      firstname: this.firstName,
      lastname: this.lastName,
    };
    this.dialogRef.close(person);
  }
}
```

dialog.component.html

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Add or Update Person</h2>
<mat-dialog-content>
<form #f="ngForm">
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Firstname</mat-label>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="firstName" name="firstname" required [value]="firstName" placeholder="Firstname" />
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Lastname</mat-label>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="lastName" name="firstname" required [value]="lastName" placeholder="Lastname"/>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions>
  <button (click)="addOrUpdatePerson()" class="btn-confirm" mat-button mat-dialog-close cdkFocusInitial>Save</button>
  <button class="btn-cancel" mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true">Cancel</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed initializing data in DialogComponent, you can do it like this

```
  firstName: string = '';
  lastName: string = '';
  constructor(
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public person: Person
  ) {
    if (person) {
      this.firstName = person.firstname;
      this.lastName = person.lastname;
    }
  }
```

The second issue, that there isn't logic to update persons array
Below is only example, becouse it depends on your needs

```
updatePerson(person: Person) {
    this.dialog
      .open(DialogComponent, { data: person })
      .afterClosed()
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.persons.shift();
        this.persons.unshift(data)
       
        console.log(this.persons);
      });
  }
```

Demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xnwcmz?file=src%2Fglobal_styles.css,src%2Fmain.ts